# "Cannot read property 'mergeConfig' of undefined" error while Installing VueJS

Tags: php, laravel-5, gulp, vue.js

On Installing `VueJS` while running Gulp in Laravel Project, I get following:

```
Me-MBP:simpleb2b AdnanAhmad$ gulp build
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs//myProject//node_modules/laravel-elixir-vue/main.js:4
    Elixir.webpack.mergeConfig({
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'mergeConfig' of undefined
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs//myProject/node_modules/laravel-elixir-vue/main.js:4:19
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs//myProject//node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/index.js:29:16
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at global.Elixir (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs//myProject//node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/index.js:28:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs//myProject//gulpfile.js:16:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
```

Comment: Are you sure you ran `npm install` and all went well before it? Which versions of node/npm are you using?

Comment: @J.Bruni `v6.3.0` - Yes I did run.

Comment: Maybe there are missing dependencies at `package.json`... can you include its contents in the question? It looks like `webpack` itself is missing.

Comment: Maybe installing `laravel-elixir-webpack-official` can solve the issue... but if this is the case I wonder why it wasn't already at package.json... `npm install laravel-elixir-webpack-official --save-dev`

Comment: Did you find an fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

Deleting and rebuilding `\node_modules` didn't change anything for me.

Try

```
npm install --save laravel-elixir-webpack-official
```

After this gulp should work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem resolves me by running npm install and run gulp with git-bash cmd.
note:make sure you install gulp globally as recommended [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir)